# Sort array (stdClass Object)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, object

Getting this result after array_merge of 2 arrays:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [tid] => 3954 [name] => Alleman ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [tid] => 3958 [name] => Jack ) 
        [2] => stdClass Object ( [tid] => 3963 [name] => Aquin Catholic ));
```

I want to sort the array by [name]. I have been reading and searching for hours but cannot figure out how to sort passed the stdClass Object to [name].

Have tried sort, ksort, uasort, etc. wont sort passed the stdClass Object to [name].

Example

```
function compareItems($a, $b)
{
if ( $a->name < $b->name ) return -1;
if ( $a->name > $b->name ) return 1;
return 0; // equality
}

uasort($players, "compareItems");
```

Comment: What result do you get instead of what you expect? Your code should work exactly as you have it.

Comment: It is sorting by array key value, instead of 'Name' value within each array

Comment: It looks like it works fine. http://codepad.viper-7.com/k0ebJm  Post a little more code if it isn't doing what you expect. You may have a logic problem somewhere.